# Change Bootstrap Switch Depending on Leaflet Layer Zoom

Tags: javascript, leaflet, zoom, bootstrap-framework

I have this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joshuadickerson92/s537t380/3/) that as you can see has two tile layers. I have set the `minZoom` of the 'Example Layer' to 5 so that it only loads once you have zoomed in that far.

The issue is, using [Bootstrap Switch](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/) I cannot get the switch for the 'Example Layer' to be disabled until the user zooms in to zoom 5 in this case and then the layer would be visible.

The ideal solution would add a tooltip to show on to the switch whilst it is disabled that advises the user to zoom in further to view the layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may provide a partial answer.  Use the map event listener to listen for zoomend to toggle the state of your bootstrap switch.

```
map.on('zoomend', function (e) {
          // enable/disable based on zoom level
          if (map.getZoom()>=5) {
              $("[name='my-checkbox2']").bootstrapSwitch('disabled',false);
              }
        else if (map.getZoom()<5) {
          $("[name='my-checkbox2']").bootstrapSwitch('disabled',true);
        }});
```

See the updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s537t380/6/).  I also set the initial state of the button to 'disabled'.  When you zoom to level 5 or higher the button will become enabled, and when zoom level goes back below 5 the button will be disabled once again.

Comment: That's an excellent answer, thanks. I had tried an event listener but hadn't figured that bit out. I won't mark as accepted yet as it would be great if when the switch was disabled a tooltip told the user why this was the case.